# Azure Service Bus - PeekBatchAsync returning less messages than expected

Tags: vb.net, azure, azureservicebus

In an Azure Service Bus Topic I have a subscription with more than 1000 messages. These messages are consumed by a worker role.
For monitoring purposes, I want to peek first 10 messages, to see what kind of messages are waiting to be processed. To accomplish that task I create a subscriptionclient and I call method PeekBatchAsync . The strange behavior is that sometimes PeekBatchAsync returns less than 10 messages (i.e. 2 or 4 messages).

Code Example :

```
Dim subscriptionClient As SubscriptionClient = messagingFactory.CreateSubscriptionClient(topicName, subscriptionName)
Dim messages = Await subscriptionClient.PeekBatchAsync(10)
```

More information to clarify the context:

- I am sure that the subscription contains more than 1000 messages
- The topic was created with EnablePartitioning = True
- I'm using library Microsoft.ServiceBus v. 2.3.4.0
- I'm using sessions
- The most of the time I got the right number of messages (10) and sometimes I got less messages. I can't figure out what are the exact conditions to replicate the issue

My question is : Why sometimes the method returns less messages than expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the documentation for the Azure-ServiceBus [`ReceiveBatch`-method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj673154.aspx) also applies in the case of `PeekBatchAsync`. Basically it says: The max. number of messages (in your case 10) might be returned but it's not guaranteed.

I experienced better results when applying the overload taking two parameters: (`int messageCount, TimeSpan serverWaitTime`), where one can define a wait-time.

Comment: Unfortunately, PeekBatch/PeekBatchAsync doesn't have the overload with the timespan parameters, so I cannot try. Maybe the documentation of PeekBatch/PeekBatchAsync should be updated with the fact that the number of elements is not guaranteed even if the subscription contains more elements.

Comment: @Daniele: Even though I experienced better results with `TimeSpan` but still I do receive less messages than specified from time to time. Also, the order of the messages is not guaranteed by default!